# What is the meaning of 'for' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

It was a mistake **for** us to come here tonight.

Comment: It doesn't have a 'meaning', it's just the preposition introducing the nature of the mistake.

Comment: "For" is a meaningless subordinator marking the start of the non-finite clause in which "us" is the subject.

Comment: Can you show me an equivalent sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It was a mistake* [*for us to come here tonight*].

"For" has no meaning here. It's a subordinator marking the start of the bracketed non-finite clause.

Where a *to*-infinitival clause contains a subject, it also contains the meaningless clause subordinator "for", which appears at the beginning of the clause, right before the subject, in this case "us".

Briefly, the history of "for" goes back to the preposition "for", but this "for" behaves as a clause subordinator.

Other examples include:

> [***For** John to lose his temper like that*] *is very unusual.*
>
> *We can't afford* [***for** everyone to travel business class*.]

Comment: John's loss of temper like that is very unusual.=For John to lose his temper like that is very unusual.                Are both the sentences equivalent in meaning?

Comment: @Sam More or less, yes.

Answer (score 1):

*For* in this sentence has no meaning; it's part of a larger construction, the *for...to* complementizer that introduces infinitive clauses. There are two parts to the complementizer -- *for* marks the subject of the infinitive clause, if it's present, and *to* marks the verb phrase of the infinitive clause.

- ***For** [him] **to** [leave early] would be a good idea*.

In the sentence above, *him* is the subject of *leave early*, and the infinitive clause *for him to leave early* is the subject of *would be a good idea*. Infinitives are always subordinate clauses, and they're non-finite (they're not inflected for past or present tense), and they are very common in many constructions.

The complementizer *for* is usually not present in most infinitives; it's required when an infinitive clause with a subject begins the sentence, as above. But if you extrapose that infinitive to the end and leave a dummy *it* behind, you get

- ***It** would be a good idea (for him) to leave early*.

the *for him* subject can be deleted, as infinitive subjects often are

- *It would be a good idea to leave early*.

The *to* doesn't have any meaning, either; they're both just part of the machinery.